# time-series formating: Cannot replicate a time-series format

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to get my data into a specific time-series format. The format I am trying to make my data is similar to the following time series format;

```
library(fpp)
data(ausbeer)

> str(ausbeer)
 Time-Series [1:211] from 1956 to 2008: 284 213 227 308 262 228 236 320 272 233 ...
```

However my data is currently the following;

```
> str(wide_DF)
 Time-Series [1:5, 1:53] from 1 to 5: 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:53] "year" "1" "2" "3" ...
```

No matter what I am trying I cannot seem to get it into the same format as the `ausbeer` data.

Any push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Data:

```
wide_DF <- structure(c(2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 0.149697356812732, 
0.506609550726262, 0.483701772054131, 0.340553948856928, 0.333626779091713, 
0.0244998111324886, 0.112120844942705, 0.0900944558373256, 0, 
0.0415224265012151, 0.0550537737139359, 0.17295508953821, 0.163929433720004, 
0.0576641678554561, 0.0906564289945531, 0.0274508134712055, 0.16192922040378, 
0.142555512496348, 0.0625454708565096, 0.0713307780915137, 0.213984247872558, 
0.388163795230051, 0.164139722545731, 0.0770529539010844, 0.0938540183343052, 
0.0783422018092716, 0.227206496783438, 0.35237013136599, 0.258504104665886, 
0.321155525044278, 0.0310253280164216, 0.145802804370329, 0.235904612124217, 
0.099505662356445, 0.184479613065924, 0.0541816334844162, 0.171606159981382, 
0.115107342701831, 0.0741165588765761, 0.108561719279517, 0.0806492605345567, 
0.154086848847159, 0.128553880389704, 0.0619227096142703, 0.102441840801919, 
0.0877855302949306, 0.210374588670803, 0.168914894757668, 0.0892981276862553, 
0.107796585571731, 0.152766825529036, 0.197064573460434, 0.157147609673816, 
0.0794331221751312, 0.130178451495829, NA, 0.288013610146669, 
0.218033903861127, 0.144165085504355, 0.265694549788369, 0.168423392180753, 
0.220217969236187, 0.192778260148724, 0.0616202640553713, 0.208895233807108, 
0.172908899350928, 0.273558409751774, NA, 0.131826476698887, 
0.214943212753592, 0.185482743591095, NA, 0.264010141661686, 
0.137209722798776, NA, 0.213353668598008, 0.288506341574192, 
0.265934476984103, 0.166437178815794, 0.213012834405297, 0.229097493059307, 
0.326273737259306, 0.209431740094857, NA, 0.240648159088921, 
0.261158363124192, 0.317036580243605, 0.244681209115455, 0.166687664239444, 
0.240465787771525, 0.282936314890266, 0.376241375996475, 0.288711990429523, 
0.218930682309907, 0.294307615813644, 0.340039521860067, 0.381665974567176, 
0.289509990005749, 0.222712288785976, 0.302326040229749, 0.592897079173477, 
0.707453475415865, 0.315092875222347, 0.238746934161925, 0.360467454111782, 
0.437728811188524, 0.485169961326965, 0.686681695697921, 0.513927986995597, 
0.657805801598166, 0.413066850628898, 0.420451063363391, 0.452317417206126, 
0.392680063685442, 0.467494633248041, 0.490885152462683, 0.449702773878119, 
0.374537214449401, 0.314372316775567, 0.352543088557757, 0.456852949424961, 
0.502821656395841, 0.473850571102317, 0.37271347773425, 0.468025614416299, 
0.492964518353547, 0.491841956261615, 0.451832204837682, 0.330054166675406, 
0.452103599554613, 0.972882256833953, 1, 0.836981605987354, 0.735454399633936, 
0.625060089794185, 0.420276672512582, 0.44763479957363, 0.51920428542675, 
0.484249008420553, 0.828415542650317, 0.439876590158875, 0.458798662510525, 
0.446969106246101, 0.329267937698866, 0.402265340895058, 0.443357095278529, 
0.48161107578401, 0.421502554574427, 0.35492302612805, 0.389391661815002, 
0.480802216652516, 0.496614239968388, 0.41709701215027, 0.355395255525041, 
0.427983230181801, 0.426624787626307, 0.47619764751241, 0.390323036410375, 
0.346946500338582, 0.444962482661289, 0.398178487457366, 0.460418831412368, 
0.365705653465875, 0.314414354295281, 0.404995279601097, 0.395484743345358, 
0.447895106385658, 0.333904920716383, 0.315905256117267, 0.38580728350725, 
0.61293865090702, 0.392285202440178, 0.300121453991199, 0.318457847197856, 
0.382196506098525, 0.42777529076777, 0.655937896884758, 0.579486246422688, 
0.512463359506227, 0.601431192394729, 0.283409977946298, 0.430264772601089, 
0.321055545570556, 0.311027552565597, 0.419878449584049, 0.295947790026711, 
0.323869738229137, 0.215519275318642, 0.192393768801782, 0.326484958316528, 
0.317550712975473, 0.303764772399812, 0.215565915142833, 0.177813119709567, 
0.288920671391334, 0.299640010568774, 0.258602815268962, 0.208650826721134, 
0.192887375961921, 0.273866371013686, 0.300719638221296, 0.260930408982457, 
0.214130384575884, 0.20094859121612, 0.262324215127644, 0.291610161608615, 
0.240764266638331, 0.232400949526744, 0.190638711181672, 0.194923630854379, 
0.247095733415861, 0.250696875411684, 0.17072512824086, 0.142654512656176, 
0.221234530015598, 0.336036187889497, 0.337172813493932, 0.241964382857466, 
0.188030459289294, 0.247565234387846, 0.228521023231508, 0.227452403443811, 
0.156667771761189, 0.131392002677444, 0.229392396017928, 0.213955172137217, 
0.229145352317625, 0.145988572682793, 0.1354966579701, 0.164468590746803, 
0.273338090020996, 0.28521986301974, 0.199009246024986, 0.178427989941778, 
0.218632123403024, 0.485758317106326, 0.478231444703654, 0.371723057102618, 
0.358665186970456, 0.437144925882923, 0.143782632825279, 0.132760650342865, 
0.0511910889931185, 0.0421970278185858, 0.0830346125807046, 0.169335703112876, 
0.127452787871597, 0.0947298145120868, 0.0660661513870076, 0.136073219608577, 
0.328666970899003, 0.296331593970631, 0.154669507656273, 0.12819972894051, 
0.134629124753297, 0.491065758190125, 0.47654036029283, 0.357442986752192, 
NA, 0.388556693139287), .Dim = c(5L, 53L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("year", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
    "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", 
    "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", 
    "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", 
    "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", 
    "51", "52")), .Tsp = c(1, 5, 1), class = c("mts", "ts", "matrix"
))
```

EDIT:

`audbeer` shape:

```
> head(ausbeer, 32)
     Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
1956  284  213  227  308
1957  262  228  236  320
1958  272  233  237  313
1959  261  227  250  314
1960  286  227  260  311
1961  295  233  257  339
1962  279  250  270  346
1963  294  255  278  363
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I see what you're trying to do now. Let's just transpose, and fix the column names.

```
wide_df2 <- as.data.frame(t(as.data.frame(wide_DF))) 
# we need as.data.frame() twice here to strip the ts class, and then add the data.frame class back after t()
```

Set the first row as column names:

```
names(wide_df2) <- wide_df2[1,]
```

Remove the column names from the data:

```
wide_df2 <- wide_df2[-1, ]
```

And convert back to `ts`:

```
wide_df2 <- ts(wide_df2)


         2008      2009       2010       2011       2012
1  0.14969736 0.5066096 0.48370177 0.34055395 0.33362678
2  0.02449981 0.1121208 0.09009446 0.00000000 0.04152243
3  0.05505377 0.1729551 0.16392943 0.05766417 0.09065643
4  0.02745081 0.1619292 0.14255551 0.06254547 0.07133078
5  0.21398425 0.3881638 0.16413972 0.07705295 0.09385402
6  0.07834220 0.2272065 0.35237013 0.25850410 0.32115553
7  0.03102533 0.1458028 0.23590461 0.09950566 0.18447961
8  0.05418163 0.1716062 0.11510734 0.07411656 0.10856172
```

Comment: Thanks! This is how I had the data originally, however this was not the same shape as the `ausbeer` data. So I used the following to make it into the same shape `wide_DF <- df %>% 
  spread(week, dollarmm)`

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to keep the years on the left and the weeks on the top. When I run `plot(as.ts(wide_df2))` I get 5 plots (one for each year). I was hoping to get it in the same format as `ausbeer` since I am following closely this tutorial.

Comment: @user113156 maybe `ts(wide_DF[ , -1], start = 2008)`?

Comment: I get this: `Error in plotts(x = x, y = y, plot.type = plot.type, xy.labels = xy.labels,  : 
  cannot plot more than 10 series as "multiple"`

Comment: You can't plot more than 10 time series at a time using `plot` at least with default settings. `plot( ts(wide_DF[,-1], start = 2008)[,1:5])` will work